# Grouping columns in Seaborn barplots

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a data frame consisting of 32 columns and I wish to generate a bar plot using Seaborn with 8 different groups, each consisting of 4 columns, and with each group assigned a unique color.  Each group of 4 columns represents a repeated sampling for a particular (8 different) experimental condition (they are technical replicates) and I would like to show consistency (in a purely visual manner) of sampling for each of the 8 experimental conditions.

Column structure is as follows:
**Index** | **Condition1_replicate1** | **Condition1_replicate2** ... **Condition8_replicate3** | **Condition8_replicate4**

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: It would be fine and helpful if you give a small but complete data example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a color palette that repeats 8 colors 4 times:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 32), columns=[f'Cond{i}_r{j}' for i in range(1, 9) for j in range(1, 5)])

palette = np.repeat(sns.color_palette('Set1', 8), 4, axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 3))
sns.barplot(data=df, palette=palette, ax=ax)
ax.set_xticks([])

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with repeated colors]

PS: You can create a variation for the palette, e.g.

```py
colors = sns.color_palette('Set2', 8)
palette = [color_j for color_i in colors for color_j in sns.dark_palette(color_i, 7)[-4:]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 3))
sns.barplot(data=df, palette=palette, ax=ax)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1.5, 4 * 8, 4))
ax.set_xticklabels([f'Condition {i}' for i in range(1, 9)])
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with different palette]

Comment: Excellent this is great, more than I was hoping for. The xticklabels line is also very useful. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks - I'm new to StackOverflow ;)